# Iterate over list of lists by the X coordinate?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

If I have a list of lists like this:

```
private List<List<int>> tileLayer = new List<List<int>>(50);
```

I want to check if all elements in a "Column" are equal to -1. (I'm aware that columns are a thing only with 2D arrays, but I don't know how to better describe it or if it is even possible)

If they are, Remove this column and all after it.

LINQ or not, doesn't matter, I'm at a loss on how to do this.

I already implemented the removal of "Rows" like this:

```
if (tileLayer[i].All(x => x == -1)) {
    int rowsToDelete = tileLayer.Count - i;
    tileLayer.RemoveRange(i, rowsToDelete);
}
```

But as I said I'm not sure how to do it with columns. Also using a 2D array is not possible, I need it to be dynamic.

Comment: Provide an example array and what would be the desired o/p?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Set columnIndex to the column you want to check. If all values in that column are -1, we will remove that column from all your row lists.

```
    int columnIndex = 5; // Set to whatever column you want to check
    var shouldRemove = true;

    // Loop through the columns and check if they equal -1
    foreach (List<int> t in tileLayer)
    {
        if (t[columnIndex] != -1)
        {
            shouldRemove = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    // If all the columns were -1, remove that column
    if (shouldRemove)
    {
        foreach (List<int> t in tileLayer)
        {
            // Remove this column from the List<int>
            t.RemoveRange(columnIndex, t.Count - columnIndex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works, but I need to also remove all the columns after the one at `columnIndex`, so I modified it to use `RemoveRange` and it works!

Comment: OK I updated my answer to remove all columns after index. Yes you can write a generic function CheckAndRemoveColumn(List<int> tileRow, int columnIndex) with all that code in it, then just call that function 4 times for each of your 4 lists.

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare a variable `bool delete = false`
2. Go through the outer list with a for loop or a foreach loop

In the loop:

1. Check if the item at the column position you want is not null and equals -1
2. When it is: set `delete = true` and break out of the loop

After the loop:

1. Check if `delete == true`
2. When it is: Go through the outer list with a for loop or a foreach loop again and delete the elements at/behind the column position